# Show/Hide - jQuery issues

Tags: jquery, css

I have had numorous of problems whilst building [this](http://molossi.psm2.co.uk/index-rwj.php) website, especially with Internet Explorer.

When contact is clicked it messes up the animation and then once again when cancel has been clicked.

I have also used [Spark JS](http://sparkjs.co.uk), but this too seems to play up (only in IE).

Spark tests are here:
[Spark 2](http://molossi.psm2.co.uk/index-spark2.php)
[Spark 3](http://molossi.psm2.co.uk/index-rw.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having a css issue, especially if the problem exists while using two different javascript libraries. Hide the div without using any animation and get the css positioning set, then add in the animation.

Also, there is no reason to use jQuery `live()` if all of the content for every page is loaded at once.

Edit: Hmmm, after looking a bit more it might be the `positionFooter()` function that is having issues. Try adding a `position: relative` to your container then `position: absolute` to the footer and position it using `bottom:0` instead of calculating a new `top` constantly. That way it is attached to the container block and there shouldn't be a need to use the `positionFooter()` function in the first place.

---

Edit: ok, at the top of your page, inside the `<style>` section add this:

```
.container { position: relative; }
#footer { position: absolute; bottom: -100px; clear: both; }
```

then disable the `positionFooter()` function.

Comment: Thanks, just trying this now. Where does the bottom:0 go? And do I need to remove any CSS properties? :)

Comment: When I do this the footer plays up (Chrome + IE) with the position: absolute. But when I change it to static: works fine on chrome but IE plays up. :/

Comment: The `bottom:0` should just be put into the base css. Then get rid of the `positionFooter()` function all together.

Comment: @fudgey That's on the index.php, I'm not using that any more. I am doing a rewite. See the links above, not the root. Thanks :) Base css?

Comment: Hmmm ok, it needs to be `bottom:-100px` instead. I've updated my post above.

Comment: it works fine on Chrome. Works ok (ish) on IE, it sort of shows the animation and leaves the footer at the bottom, this is an improvement. Is there anything else which could improve it? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is maybe adding an `overflow:hidden` to the `.container` class. That way in IE the stuff that is floating doesn't show off to the right while the animation is happening.

Comment: That cuts part of the footer off and fails to show contact div.

Comment: Thanks for your help! IE is such a pain! What IE was you testing it on? I was on IE 7.

Comment: I was using IE9 in IE7 browser mode.

Comment: Ok. What's it like in IE9, I am unable to test it today as I'm not at work. I have IE7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: IE9 acts pretty much like every other modern browser, so it looks okay :)